# If $u$ and $v$ satisfy Cauchy Riemann, then $u_1 = u^2-v^2$ and $v_1 = 2uv$ also satisfy

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

If $u$ and $v$ satisfy Cauchy Riemann, then:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$

I have to show that

a)

$$u_1 = u^2-v^2, v_1 = 2uv$$

also satisfies. So let's begin calculating the partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 2u\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

therefore

$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y}$$

Now, the other condition:

$$\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 2u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$

which implies in:

$$\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}$$

Did I do it right? Because it seems this would almost always work. Could somebody shine a light?

**UPDATE**

As pointed below in the comments, I should differentiate $u$ and $v$ with respect to $x$, then it should look like this for the first Cauchy equality:

$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y} = 2\left(u\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) = 2\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)$$

therefore

$$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Sorry but they are not correct. When you take the derivatives you should consider both $u,v$ as functions of $(x,y)$.

Comment: @iamvegan should I do $\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$?

Comment: @iamvegan would you mind taking a look now? I updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated version of your post looks correct. However when differentiating $u_1$, I would just directly do it, instead of the chain rule. The following looks more natural to me.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u_1 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u^2 - v^2)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u^2 - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}v^2\\
&=2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - 2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: that's rigth, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not what you want but I still think it's cute. Since $u, v$ satisfy the CR-equations, then $f(z) = u+iv$ is analytic. In particular,  $f(z)^2$ is also analytic since multiplication of analytic functions is still analytic. Observe $f(z)^2 = u^2-v^2+2i uv$, which means $u^2-v^2$ and $2uv$ must satisfy the CR-equations.

Comment: This is actually cute :) (+1)